# how to store or print data of submit button

Tags: php, forms, post, button, request

I have GET value passed in from a form from the previous page and I want to check which of two submit buttons were pressed. I'm using GET just to debug for now. One button has a value="Update" and the other is value="Delete". Both buttons have name="updateORdelete". I can't seem to GET POST or REQUEST 'updateORdelete' into a variable. The URL looks like

```
&updateORdelete>%0D%0A%09%09%09<input+type%3D=Update
```

I don't know why there's so many symbols instead of &updateORdelete=Update. Some of the forum people say to use parse_str() but it doesn't work as well. Here is the code I tried:

```
<?php
$updateORdelete = $_REQUEST['updateORdelete'];
parse_str($updateORdelete, $updel);
print $updel;?>
```

This doesn't give me anything except a printed "Array". So I thought since it thinks it's an array, i'd just implode it into a string and then print out the new variable. But after doing so, nothing gets printed out either. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: why are you giving same name for two buttons, if you want to find out which one is pressed?

Comment: That's valid - it's treated like checkboxes... the value from the button that was pressed will be passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the URL you included, I suspect your HTML code is missing a close-quote in the `name="updateOrdelete"` attribute on one or both of your buttons.

Please post your HTML code though so we can see for sure.

Comment: Wow, you are freakin genius. I don't know how you suspected that out from just the url, but I guess that kind of instinct comes with practice. Thanks! My question seems so dumb now, I'm probably going to delete it. haha